# AWS topic creation sporadic failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I have a test that uses AWS SDK and creates a topic. The test mostly works but sometimes it fails with this error(not always but at random)

`46 AWS: unknown error: subscriptionARN= InvalidParameter: Invalid parameter: SubscriptionArn Reason: An ARN must have at least 6 elements, not 1`

In the case when the subscription failed, this is how my topic looked though(from logs of the test)
`arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:786578629570:pubsub_test_2b9b01e7-69e4-43c2-b069-4e5d91a77f2f`

What could be the potential cause of this? This is a test that talks to AWS and not cloudstack

Comment: Note that `SubscriptionArn` != topic ARN and the ARN you show looks like the topic ARN.

Answer (score 3):

the six elements looks like something like this:

**arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789:topic_name_you_create**

What you will do is first create a topic then try to redo your action again and select this topic you've create in the TOPIC ARN.

This should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a space at the beginning of the Topic name.
So, you need to SELECT a TOPIC from the drop-down, not text it, and make sure arn parameters are presented before the TOPIC name `arn:aws:sns:server-location:id:topic-name`